# Transfer bundle identifer from objc to swift 3 project

Tags: xcode

I have an ios project that has been developed entirely in objective c. There are already a large number of users in the objective c project but I want to transfer it to swift 3 altogether.

I'm planning on doing s redesign of the app and would love to be able to start a new ios project in swift 3 and give it the bundle identifier of the objective c project.

Is this possible? Will the app store have any issues when i submit a build that is a whole new project but with the same bundle identifier?

Thank you

Comment: **Nobody knows what the app store will do.**  Having said that, I can't see where you would have a problem.  If I have an O-C project and replace all the files with Swift files, it's still the same project as far as identity goes.

Comment: @PhillipMills i don't want to transfer all of the files I want to use an entirely new project. Thanks

Comment: App store doesn't see you project. App store sees only the provisioning profile, your certificate and compiled code. Creating a new project means absolutely nothing for app store.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

The app's bundle id is the only required item to be the same between both projects for submitting to the App Store.  Setting the display name as the same is only necessary so that it looks the same on user's devices.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

You should be able to do this with a completely new project.  You will need to make sure that you code sign your new app with the same provisioning profiles and certificates and set the Display Name and Bundle Identifier as the exact same as your existing obj-c app.

Then you should be able to submit a build to a new version on the App Store.

I suggest creating the new project for swift and submitting a build to iTunesConnect and make sure it shows up. Just so that you know that you can successfully submit with your new project before writing all the code.

Comment: You do not need the same certificates and provisioning profiles or display name. The ONLY thing that matters is the app's bundle id. Everything else can be different and it will be treated as a normal app update.